# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to the android platform, but my company forcing me to do it, please help.

I am running the android app from android studio and getting this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Illegal char <:> at index 115: D:\works\android2\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\apk\eLogistics-.v3.0.3-b8baa74-2021-08-02-12:39.44.2.apk

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Did many suggestions given in stack overflow, but didn't work anything.

Please help me.

app/build.gradle file code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html' // use 'javadoc' to get standard java docs
    outputDirectory = "$project.rootDir/documentation"
    configuration {
        includeNonPublic = true
        skipEmptyPackages = true
        skipDeprecated = true
        reportUndocumented = false
        jdkVersion = 8
    }
}

android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        def fileNaming = "apk/eLogistics"
        def value = 0

        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1
        }

        def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 1
        def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def versionNumber = versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            applicationId "com.webninja.elogistics"
            versionCode gitVersionCode
            versionName gitVersionName
            versionNameSuffix ''
            // versionName "${getVersionNameTimestamp()}-${versionBuild}"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 28
            android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
            apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
            apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "v1.0.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        buildTypes {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(project.rootProject.file("config.properties").newDataInputStream())
            def tmdbApiKey = properties.getProperty("apiBase", "a")
            debug {
                buildConfigField 'String', "API_BASE", tmdbApiKey
                resValue 'string', "api_base", tmdbApiKey
            }

            release {
                buildConfigField 'String', "API_BASE", tmdbApiKey
                resValue 'string', "api_base", tmdbApiKey

                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${fileNaming}-.${gitVersionName}.$versionBuild.2.apk"
                // outputFileName = "${fileNaming}-${getVersionNameTimestamp()}-${versionBuild}-${outputFile.name}"
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true;
}

dependencies {
    def moshiVersion = "1.8.0"
    def retrofit2_version = "2.5.0"
    def okhttp3_version = "3.12.0"
    def kotlinCoroutineVersion = "1.1.0"
    def nav_version = "2.2.0"
    def lottieVersion = "3.3.1"
    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"


    // ...
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:google-direction-library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0-M2'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "com.twilio:chat-android:3.1.1"
    implementation 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.TutorialsAndroid:KAlertDialog:v7.0.19'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.0.2'
    implementation "com.pubnub:pubnub-gson:4.29.1"
    implementation 'com.appolica:interactive-info-window:v1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.andrefrsousa:SuperBottomSheet:1.5.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')



    // Image
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // logging
    implementation 'com.noveogroup.android:android-logger:1.3.1'

    //Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    //Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    //Retrofit2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2"

    //Okhttp3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinCoroutineVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutineVersion"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // RX
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.uber.autodispose2:autodispose-lifecycle:2.0.0'

    //View Pager 2
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

    // material support designs
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.17.4'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.17.4'

    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.17.4'

    //sentry
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:5.0.1'
    
    dependencies {
        def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

        // ViewModel and LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"


    }
    implementation 'com.github.nekoloop:Base64Image:0.1.0'
    //Signature Pad
    implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    // Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'


    //Room
    //def room_version = "2.2.0"

    //implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    //annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    //kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

}

def getVersionNameTimestamp() {
    return new Date().format('MM.dd.yyHH')
}

def getVersionCodeTimestamp() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('MMddyyHH')
    def code = formattedDate.toInteger()
    println sprintf("VersionCode: %d", code)
    return code
}
```

Comment: paste more lines, it should say which file has the illegal char <:>  probably you have it in a layout xml file?

Comment: D:\works\android2\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\apk\eLogistics-.v3.0.3-b8baa74-2021-08-02-12:39.44.2.apk  it saying in apk file name there is a illegal char.

Comment: you can paste your app/build.gradle file .

Comment: pasted. please check

Comment: remove the line outputFileName to see what happen

Comment: 08:48 AM Failed to commit install session 1078006449 with command cmd package install-commit 1078006449. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user

08:48 AM Error
    Installation did not succeed.
    The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED

Comment: ViewModel and Live data dependencies are nested try flattening them

Comment: I am new to it. can you elaborate more @Anshul

Comment: there is a `dependencies` tag inside a `dependencies` tag , try removing it